# How can I add more storage to my Ubuntu partition without erasing data?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

Answers to similar questions don't work for me. I left an unallocated 200 GB from my windows partition. I'm dual booting with Ubuntu. And when I try to give the 200 GB of unallocated space to the Ubuntu partition, I can't. The partition of 200 GB is named "free space" in Spanish, because I don't use it in English.

How can I add it? I'm using the partition tool from the USB installation of Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) and [How to enlarge Ubuntu system partition to the left?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100343/how-to-enlarge-ubuntu-system-partition-to-the-left) If those pages don’t help you, please [edit] your question to elaborate on what not worked for you.

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `gparted`, and then I can make the best recommendation. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: As @heynnema suggests, we would need to see parted output or some other representation of the disk layout. Any recommendations without more information is irresponsible given it could result in data loss. You talk of 'unallocated space' but it sounds like you have a 200GB partition with or without a file system. You can't expand one partition into another so if true, you would need to remove that partition. The resulting free space would also need to be adjacent to the Ubuntu partition to grow into, but again; need to see the disk layout.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there are two possible problems here.

First, you cannot move or resize a partition while your operating system is running from it. Meaning, if you are running the Ubuntu installation, you cannot increase the size of its partition. You will need to run an OS from somewhere else.

Second, I'm assuming you had Windows before you installed Ubuntu. In that case, your Ubuntu partition is probably displayed to the right in `gparted`, with the free space you removed from the Windows partition to the left of it. Problem is, a partition can only be expanded towards the right, so if the free space is to the left of your Ubuntu partition, you will need to move the Ubuntu partition to the left, and then expand it towards the right.

How I suggest doing so:

1. As always, when messing with partitions, **backup your data.**
2. Make a [GParted live bootable USB stick](https://gparted.org/download.php).
3. Boot into that, just like you did with the Ubuntu installer, and open `gparted`
4. Select your Ubuntu partition
5. At the top, click Partition>Resize/Move
6. Move it to the left, and expand it to the right and fill the 200GB.

Comment: General idea is OK, but without seeing a `gparted` screenshot, you can't be sure that there aren't other partitions in the way. You can't guess/assume with this.

Comment: @heynnema, I agree. I would have asked for a screenshot in a comment, but I need 50 reputation to post one. Do you know of a good way for me to ask for such clarification in the future, without having to post a comment?

Comment: You just posted a comment :-) If you look at the 2nd comment on the original question, you'll see I asked for the `gparted` screenshot, and so far, they've not responded.

Comment: @heynnema Haha yes, I realize. I might have been unclear. I meant to post a comment on the OP post. I cannot reply to the question with a comment, I need 50 reputation, so I was wondering how to ask for such clarification in the future, before I have 50 rep.?

Comment: Ah, just keep posting answers until you get the required 50 pts :-)

Comment: @heynnema Alright, then. Thanks for the feedback, I will :)