# Resize a particular partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I know this question is common but yet i cant find an answer to it and I am seriously scared to do this.

So please guide me step by step if possible,

I have a dual boot linux and windows. However currently my root is running out of space as there is only 20GB which I allocated . So how do I increase the size of my root. I want to use My Linux (F) to increase it.

Please refer to my screenshot

[My Partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXk4u.png)

From what I have researched, people say have to reinstall again and some of them have advised to use partition manager which I don't know how to use. None of these advises have clear cut answers.

Hopefully someone can guide me through this please.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) I am sorry your question is pretty unclear. Your screenshot comes clearly from Windows but Windows cannot read the contents of Linux partitions. Moreover, your partition called Linux (F:) uses NTFS which is a _Windows_ filesystem. No other partition is identified in your screenshot… You should run GParted in Linux to provide more information on your partitions as GParted can get information from both Linux and Windows partitions.

Comment: @Melebius His Linux F is just windows partition he mounts in linux and in windows. Other three partitions are linux partitions. The question is maybe about how to resize root partition to the left in case of linux F: partition shrinking from windows.

Comment: @gyru yes u are partially correct.  What I am asking is how to increase the size of the root which is 20gb to 80gb using the mounted Linux f drive

Comment: See also [How to enlarge Ubuntu system partition to the left?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100343/how-to-enlarge-ubuntu-system-partition-to-the-left) Thank you @Gryu for figuring it out.